# Alpine Linux Hangs During Boot at: " successfully initialized wpa_supplicant"

Tags: boot, wifi, ntp, alpine-linux

I installed Alpine Linux on Intel Compute Stick with 32 Bit Atom Processor.

After installation I followed the procedure laid out here for connecting to internet via wlan0 port: [Connecting to a wireless access point](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Connecting_to_a_wireless_access_point).

However during boot it hangs up with this last message:

```
"successfully initialized wpa_supplicant"
```

It hangs for a long long time and a manual intervention with Ctrl+C is required to move past this step.

One solution is to start internet after booting completes so that it does not hijack the booting process - However non availability of internet during boot causes Chronyd NTP client to fail as it needs access to internet.

Comment: Just a stab-in-the-dark - is this caused by the SSH service slowing down the boot?  Try temporarily disabling it.

Comment: @garethTheRed It doesn’t seem to be Ssh. Saying this because after CTRL+C it reports two other success messages regarding internet connection before moving on. So I’d assert it has everything to do with wpa_supplicant.

Comment: OK.  Just for info though - in my case Alpine was hanging for a while (starting SSH) due to a lack of entropy.  Installing `haveged` fixed it.  There's a similar complaint about wpa_supplicant causing a delay on the [Gentoo Forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1081710-start-0.html)

Comment: Ah! Ok thanks that is a positive lead. Let me try that out. I will report back the outcome  here.

Comment: @garethTheRed `haveged` is well pointed out. It is a necessity in simple systems that have a low entropy from the hw, such as VMs or ioTs like the rpi.

Comment: Added haveged and Added it to runlevel boot. Did not work. I have same problem.

Comment: The thing is haveged starts after the wpa_supplicant starts. Trying to figure a way to specify runorder.

Comment: @garethTheRed Rui F Ribeiro Tried installing haveged. The problem is I am not able to initialize it to run before wpa_supplicant fires up during boot. However as you said it is definitely seems an entropy problem. If I punch exactly 6 random keys on keyboard then that satisfies the entropy needs the wpa_supplicant immediately continues with next steps and successful connection.

Comment: That's odd.  I'm not using wpa_supplicant so can't experiment with this.  However, take a look at the `depends()` section of the init scripts.  Use [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Initscripts#Dependencies) as a reference.

Comment: Also, make sure that `haveged` is started at the `boot` runlevel with `rc-update haveged boot` (you may have to remove it from default first).